# Remove all children overflowed of their parent bounds

Tags: android, removechild, object-oriented-analysis

In a special android application, I want to remove all child views from their parents if entire or a part of them was overflowed of their parents bounds (on window focus changed).

I have tried to write manual calculations on children and parent widths but I am looking for an object oriented solution to be applicable on all kinds of views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably the easiest by just extending the `ViewGroup` you are using and removing the views after layouting them. *(ViewGroups include `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, ...)*

By overwriting `onLayout` you could iterate over your children and remove any views with bounds not within of their parent.

*Things to note:* This will probably trigger another layout call, so be sure to properly handle things.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // call super to layout children and have their bounds set
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    // Iterate over all children
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getLeft() < left
                // ... add top / bottom
                || child.getRight() > right) {
            removeView(child);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to handle things without extending the `ViewGroup` you can always handle things by using the same principle after the view got layouted.